# How do I pass data from a UIViewController to UITabBarController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In UIViewController:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var points = 0

    var pressed = false

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        number = Int(sender.value)
        label.text = String(number)
    }

    @IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        pressed = true
    }
}
```

I am trying to do something in a TabBarController if a button in a UIViewController is pressed and also add a number to the number in another TabBarConroller.

[Image 1: This shows the connection between my ViewControllers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vk37.png)

[Image 2: This shows the first two ViewControllers.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZb7W.png)

[Image 3: This shows the third and fourth ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ecq5.png)

Here is my storyboard. I've put a few words to describe what I am trying to do in the images. Please tell me if you need a clearer description. Thank you!

Comment: I am not able to understand your use case, it would be helpful if you could provide us with a clearer description of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ViewController` is a child of the `UITabBarController` that you want to access, you can simply use `tabBarController` property of the `UIViewController`, e.g., use this to change selected controller to the first one:

```
@IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pressed = true

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

So let's say that you have a custom `UITabBarController` subclass, e.g.:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {


    func acceptData(points: Int) {
        print(">>> Accepted: \(points)")
        // or do anything you need to do with it
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it data as follows:

```
@IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pressed = true
    if let customTabController = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController {
        customTabController.acceptData(points: self.points)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since it seems that the current VC is presented by one of the tabBarController child controllers, you will have to access it through the `self.presentingViewController`:

```
@IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pressed = true
    if let customTabController = self.presentingViewController?.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController {
        customTabController.acceptData(points: self.points)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Your screenshot are of a very poor quality, your explanation of the problem would require a clarification too, since it is really hard to understand what you try to do. So after the whole discussion in comments I guess this is it:

```
@IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pressed = true
    if let tabController = self.presentingViewController?.tabBarController,
        let viewController3 = tabController.viewControllers?.filter({ $0 is ViewController3 }).first {

        viewController3.acceptData(points: self.points)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Milan. But what does 'self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0'?

Comment: The ViewController is a child of another TabBarController, so does that work? Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasTseng `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0` changes the selected tab in tabBarController.. it is just an example, what you want is to use `self.tabBarController` property to access `UITabBarController` and call any property/method on it.. I'll update the answer to provide a better explanation..

Comment: @ThomasTseng check it now

Comment: @ThomasTseng but this assumes that your `ViewController` is a child of the `CustomTabBarController`, if that is not the case, you will have to explain what is your hierarchy..

Comment: Again, thank you, Milan. I tried copying the code but it didn't pass the data. What should I do?

Comment: @ThomasTseng well, obviously you did not describe your problem well enough. you will have to update the question and include more information (e.g., explanation of the view controllers hierarchy, or link to the project on github, or screenshot of your storyboard, etc.)

Comment: @ThomasTseng I'll take a look at it a bit later

Comment: Thank you for the effort on helping me, Milan!

Comment: It showed me a warning "Cast from 'UITabBarController?' to unrelated type 'ViewController2' always fails" and an error "Value of type 'ViewController2' has no member 'acceptData'".

Comment: `@IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let customTabController = self.presentingViewController?.tabBarController as? FirstViewController2{

    customTabController.acceptData(points: self.points)

        }`

Comment: @ThomasTseng FirstViewController2 is obviously not a tab bar controller, why you use that one?

Comment: @ThomasTseng your project is such a mess.. naming controllers `FirstViewController2` is like the worst naming you could choose.. which one is it on the screenshots? obviously its not the tabBarControlller, but in your question you are claiming you want to send data to tabBarController.. where do you want to send them??

Comment: I am trying to send a data from ViewController2 to ViewController3(You could see the labels on the pictures). Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ThomasTseng check UPDATE 2 in the answer

Comment: It showed an "Variable used within its own initial value" error. How could I fix that?

Comment: Is there any way I could just send you the whole project?

Comment: Here is a link to my project using google drive since I don't know how to use github and don't have dropbox. I'm not sure if you could open it though. If not, please tell me. Thank you! [Project Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PPENaBtF0dX9SiWYmWSNREg8YgQoeLYq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ThomasTseng no, you did not, now the storyboards are missing

Comment: Is there any other thing missing? I added the storyboard. Here is the new link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GU_fyjhU5YSxg0Up7ACCaVj3AJ4PTaJ6?usp=sharing Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasTseng the folder is no longer accessible

Comment: Sorry, but now I changed a link.

Comment: The link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GU_fyjhU5YSxg0Up7ACCaVj3AJ4PTaJ6?usp=sharing

Comment: The contents of the folder are still not complete.. is it really so hard to share a single folder? anyway, I don't see the `submitbutton` anywhere in the code that you shared.. did you even try it?

Comment: I changed the names of a few variables so `submitbutton` isn't there. Is there anything else that is missing. I just uploaded the whole git folder from my desktop. Thank you!

Comment: Am I still missing anything? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `TabBarController` class, take a variable say **variableToBeSet**

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController
{
    var variableToBeSet: Int = 0    // This is just an example. You can change it as per requirement.
    // Rest of class implementation
}
```

Now in your `ViewController` :

```
@IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pressed = true
    let tabControllerInstance = self.tabBarController as! TabBarController
    tabControllerInstance.variableToBeSet = localVariable    // The value which you want to assign
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nitish! But after copying the code, it gave me two errors: 

1. Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2. Cast from 'UITabBarController?' to unrelated type 'SecondViewController' always fails

But I thought that the 'SecondViewController' is actually a UITabBarController

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass data as normally

```
   let vc:HomeVC = ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.getCurrentLanguageStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
   vc.tempCategoryArray = CategoryArray
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```